# Local Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f(x)$ is a positive continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ and that $f(x+u)-f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ for every given $u\in[0,\infty)$. Prove that, given any $a>0$, $f(x+u)-f(x)\to 0$, as $x\to\infty$ uniformly for $u$ over $[0,a]$.

$f$ is actually called regularly (slowly) varying function. The usual assumption is that $f$ is measurable or a Baire function. I would like to see how the stronger condition on $f$ simplifies the proof of the conclusion.